# Display all HTML elements based on Role - Need Optimized Solution

Tags: asp.net, html, database, controls, visible

I'm using ASP.Net for web development. I've situation here. say I've many HTML/ASP.Net controls on my page, and I've to set visibility of each control based on Logged-in user's role. for this I'm doing as follows:

1. Storing each Function-Name and Role combination is DB
2. During render, checking for role permission for each HTML/ASP.Net control.

e.g: Displaying something like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="Lbl1" visible='<%=CheckVisibility("Display","Admin")%>'>

public bool CheckVisibility(string FunctionName, string RoleName){
  // checks for db entry and returns bool value
}
```

Problem is, I've to do this for all the Controls. Is there any other optimized approach available to do this? please help me

Answer (score 1):

Given only your description of what you're trying to solve, I would suggest you create your own controls which inherit from the built-in ones and add some properties to them. Then the controls can do the visibility check themselves. Something like

```
namespace StackOverflowTest
{
  public class Label : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
  {
    public string DisplayRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnPreRender(e);

      Visible = PermissionHelper.CheckPermission("Display", DisplayRoles.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
  }

  public static class PermissionHelper
  {
    public static bool CheckPermission(string function, string[] allowedRoles)
    {
      // TODO: hit some sort of cache, so you don't make a bajillion queries to the DB
      return true;
    } 
  }
}
```

And then if you put this in your web.config (sorry, can't figure out how to do proper XML formatting here): `<system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
       <add tagPrefix="sot" assembly="StackOverflowTest" namespace="StackOverflowTest"/>
      </controls>
     </pages>
    </system.web>`

You can add this to your markup:
    `<sot:Label ID="AdminLabel" runat="server" Text="Bind this in OnLoad/!IsPostback or something" DisplayRoles="Admin,Management" />`

This is just one of the many ways you can do this. It all depends on the requirements, of course. But I'm pretty sure you'll need your own classes for controls to have the possibility of making it manageable.

Comment: Looks pretty! But I've many ASP.Net controls on my page. I don't want to replace all the native controls with overridden controls. can it done with ASP.net controls itself?

Comment: I suppose you could do it the way you tried to do it, by embedding the call into the Visible property, but if I remember correctly, you will have to use the databinding expression `<%#CheckVisibility()%>` instead of the standard code nugget `<%=CheckVisibility()%>` that you used in the question. And then I think you need a `DataBind()` call on the Page in the codebehind. I still think that in the long run, you'd be better off by inheriting controls and replacing them. It's so much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

C# code:

```
public enum previlageType
{
    superAdminPrevilages=1,
    partnerPrevilages = 2,
    dealerPrevilages = 3,
    customerPrevilages=4

}

if ((previlageType)Enum.Parse(typeof(previlageType), Session["previlageType"].ToString())== previlageType.partnerPrevilages)
{
    accordion.Visible = false;
}
```

ASP code:

```
<div id="accordion" runat="server">
Hello World, I'l be Hidden if a person with partner previlages is logged in. BUt will be visible if superadmin or any person except Partner logs in.
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a master page, you could get all the child page controls on load (get contentplaceholders, then get contentplaceholder controls).

Then when you have all the control names, do a lookup on your table and set its visibility to false if needed.

(below is vb but the translation should be easy.)

```
        For Each cp As String In Me.ContentPlaceHolders
            For Each ctl As Control In Me.FindControl(cp).Controls
                If adminonly.Contains(ctl.ID) Then
                    ctl.Visible = False
                End If
            Next
        Next
```